# Table parameters on stored procedure joins and autoincrement id on column name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTableCamera
(
    Id                int,
    AliasTitle        nvarchar(500),
    Make              nvarchar(500),
    Model             nvarchar(MAX) 
)
```

I have a type that is passed as a datatable to the stored procedure. I would like to firstly insert certain columns into one table if they dont exist and append the primary key id to the alias title. After this I would like to insert into the other table i.e. the image table the camera ids insert into the camera table. I need to maintain referential integrity but am unsure how to determine which id for the camera belongs to which image. I am also unsure how to append the id of the primary key to the alias titles.

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MediaGalleryFlickrImportParameters] AS TABLE
    (
        Title             nvarchar(500),
        Description       nvarchar(MAX),
        Hits              bigint,
        CameraAliasTitle  nvarchar(255),
        CameraMake        nvarchar(55),
        CameraModel       nvarchar(100)
    )
```

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTableImage
(
    Id                int,
    AliasTitle        nvarchar(500),
    Title             nvarchar(500),
    Description       nvarchar(MAX),
    Hits              bigint,
    CameraId          int
)

  CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTableCamera
(
    Id                int,
    AliasTitle        nvarchar(500),
    Make              nvarchar(500),
    Model             nvarchar(MAX) 
)
```

My procedure is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import
(   
   @dataImported [dbo].[MediaGalleryFlickrImportParameters] READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @InsertedCameraId bigint;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


/*Camera Details*/   
--IF (NOT NULLIF(@PreviousStartDate, '') IS NULL AND NOT NULLIF(@PreviousStartDate, '') IS NULL)
--BEGIN

        INSERT INTO TestTableCamera (AliasTitle, Make, Model)
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (CameraAliasTitle,'-',(SELECT ISNULL (MAX(Id)+1,0) FROM TestTableCamera)), CameraMake, CameraModel
FROM @dataImported di
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TestTableCamera c
            WHERE               
            di.CameraAliasTitle = c.AliasTitle
            AND di.CameraMake = c.Make
            AND di.CameraModel = c.Model)
AND         NOT NULLIF(di.CameraAliasTitle, '') IS NULL
            AND NOT NULLIF(di.CameraMake, '') IS NULL
            AND NOT NULLIF(di.CameraModel, '') IS NULL 

   -- SET @InsertedCameraId = (SELECT Id FROM camera WHERE make = 'tes');  
--END


INSERT INTO dbo.TestTableImage
    (Title, Description, Hits)
SELECT 
    Title, Description, Hits
FROM 
    @dataImported



END
GO
```

I thought i could do something along these lines with auto increment coloumn

```
INSERT INTO TestTableCamera (AliasTitle, Make, Model)
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (CameraAliasTitle,'-',(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id)+1,0) FROM TestTableCamera)), CameraMake, CameraModel
FROM @dataImported di
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM camera c
            WHERE 
            NOT NULLIF(di.CameraAliasTitle, '') IS NULL
            AND NULLIF(di.CameraMake, '') IS NULL
            AND NULLIF(di.CameraModel, '') IS NULL
            AND di.CameraAliasTitle = c.AliasTitle
            AND di.CameraMake = c.Make
            AND di.CameraModel = c.Model)
```

I am now handling the alias title update with a trigger, not sure if this is the best tho

```
ALTER TRIGGER InsertedCameraAlias ON TestTableCamera
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF UPDATE(Id)
          BEGIN

           UPDATE  dbo.TestTableCamera
                SET AliasTitle = Concat(a.AliasTitle,'-', a.Id)
                FROM dbo.TestTableCamera a
                JOIN inserted i ON a.ID = i.ID
                --WHERE id EXISTS IN(SELECT id from inserted)               
          END
END
GO
```

Comment: primary key on testtablecamera id, camera alias title for url purposes, camera none are allowed null now, lengths are above

Comment: updated will add an index too. How about getting the ids to insert in the relationship table tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky. I cheated towards the end…

My assumptions going in:

- From the dataset being passed in
- Extract the unique list of cameras (by alias, make, and model)
- Add them to TestTableCamera if they are not already in there

First up, I modified TestTableCamera, making the first column the primery key and setting it as an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTableCamera
(
    Id                int  identity(1,1) primary key,  --  Added identity property
    AliasTitle        nvarchar(500),
    Make              nvarchar(500),
    Model             nvarchar(MAX) 
)
```

Next, create a procedure to do the work. Comments inline on what and why:

```
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import'), 'isProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import

    @dataImported as dbo.MediaGalleryFlickrImportParameters READONLY

AS

    SET NOCOUNT on

    DECLARE @NewIds table (Id int not null)


    --  Extract list of cameras from the passed-in data
    --  Use the EXCEPT clause to filter out any items already in the target table
    --  Bonus: using EXCEPT removed dupicates
    --  Any rows added are caught by the output clause (we only need Id)
    INSERT TestTableCamera (AliasTitle, Make, Model)
     output inserted.Id
      into @NewIds
     select CameraAliasTitle, CameraMake, CameraModel
      from @dataImported
     except select AliasTitle, Make, Model
      from TestTableCamera


    --  For all rows inserted (and caught by the output clause),
    --  update their AliasTitle with the newly-generated Id.
    --  The primary key ensures that this will perform optimally
    UPDATE TestTableCamera
     set AliasTitle = AliasTitle + ' - ' + cast(ni.Id as varchar(10))
     from TestTableCamera ttc
      inner join @NewIds ni
       on ni.Id = ttc.Id

RETURN 0
GO
```

Next, test it. Created some dummy datasets

```
SET NOCOUNT on
TRUNCATE TABLE TestTableCamera

DECLARE
  @TestSet_1 dbo.MediaGalleryFlickrImportParameters


--  Four new cameras
INSERT @TestSet_1 values
  ('Title 1', 'This is the first item',  100, 'Camera Alias A', 'Make AA', 'Model 1')
 ,('Title 2', 'This is the second item', 200, 'Camera Alias A', 'Make AA', 'Model 1')
 ,('Title 3', 'This is the third item',  300, 'Camera Alias B', 'Make BB', 'Model 2')
 ,('Title 4', 'This is the fourth item', 400, 'Camera Alias C', 'Make BB', 'Model 3')
 ,('Title 5', 'This is the fifth item',  500, 'Camera Alias D', 'Make CC', 'Model 1')

EXECUTE media_gallery_flickr_import @TestSet_1

SELECT * from TestTableCamera order by Id
```

Runs this one group at a time, and things look pretty good… but that is a sign of overconfidence. Keep testing!

Set up a sequence of tests:

```
SET NOCOUNT on
TRUNCATE TABLE TestTableCamera

DECLARE
  @TestSet_1 dbo.MediaGalleryFlickrImportParameters
 ,@TestSet_2 dbo.MediaGalleryFlickrImportParameters


--  Four new cameras
INSERT @TestSet_1 values
  ('Title 1', 'This is the first item',  100, 'Camera Alias A', 'Make AA', 'Model 1')
 ,('Title 2', 'This is the second item', 200, 'Camera Alias A', 'Make AA', 'Model 1')
 ,('Title 3', 'This is the third item',  300, 'Camera Alias B', 'Make BB', 'Model 2')
 ,('Title 4', 'This is the fourth item', 400, 'Camera Alias C', 'Make BB', 'Model 3')
 ,('Title 5', 'This is the fifth item',  500, 'Camera Alias D', 'Make CC', 'Model 1')

EXECUTE media_gallery_flickr_import @TestSet_1

SELECT 'First pass' [ ], * from TestTableCamera order by Id

--  Do it again, show that nothing new comes in
EXECUTE media_gallery_flickr_import @TestSet_1

SELECT 'Second pass' [ ], * from TestTableCamera order by Id


--  One new camera, one repeat
INSERT @TestSet_2 values
  ('Title 1', 'This is a duplicate of the first item',  100, 'Camera Alias A', 'Make AA', 'Model 1')
 ,('Title 6', 'This is the sixth item',  600, 'Camera Alias E', 'Make DD', 'Model 7')

EXECUTE media_gallery_flickr_import @TestSet_2

SELECT 'Third pass' [ ], * from TestTableCamera order by Id
```

Run this, and… surprise! We’ve modified column “AliastTitle” in such as way that it will always be unique, and so will *never* match a subsequent submission of the same camera. Back to the drawing board.

I saw two options here. The first one is to put logic in the `EXCEPT` clause to return the string only up through that “ – ’ part. This is kludgy, awkward, and left as an exercise for the student.

The second option was to be lazy and add a computed  column, like so:

```
DROP TABLE TestTableCamera
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTableCamera
(
    Id                int  identity(1,1) primary key,  --  Added identity property
    AliasTitle        nvarchar(500),
    AdjustedAlias as AliasTitle + ' - ' + cast(Id as varchar(10)),
    Make              nvarchar(500),
    Model             nvarchar(MAX) 
)
```

Revise the procedure by chopping out the `output` table work:

```
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import'), 'isProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import

    @dataImported as dbo.MediaGalleryFlickrImportParameters READONLY

AS

    SET NOCOUNT on

    --  Extract list of cameras from the passed-in data
    --  Use the EXCEPT clause to filter out any items already in the target table
    --  Bonus: using EXCEPT removed dupicates
    INSERT TestTableCamera (AliasTitle, Make, Model)
     select CameraAliasTitle, CameraMake, CameraModel
      from @dataImported
     except select AliasTitle, Make, Model
      from TestTableCamera

RETURN 0
GO
```

Run the tests again, and now you get the desired results. More overconfidence? Maybe, but it seems to address the stated problem. The computed column is also kludgy, but it seems better to keep a copy of the original form of the AliasTitle. Rename the columns appropriately, and things should work out.

If nothing else, all this should give you some ideas on how to solve your problem!

---

ADDENDA, in repsonse to the comment:

Revised TestTableImage with identity property and primary, as well as foreign key to ensure that CameraId is valid:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTableImage
(
    Id                int  identity(1,1) primary key,
    AliasTitle        nvarchar(500),
    Title             nvarchar(500),
    Description       nvarchar(MAX),
    Hits              bigint,
    CameraId          int
     constraint FK_TestTableImage__TestTableCamera
      foreign key references TestTableCamera (Id)
)
```

Revised stored procedure, using TestTableCamera with the calculated column (only change is the second `INSERT` statement):

```
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import'), 'isProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.media_gallery_flickr_import

    @dataImported as dbo.MediaGalleryFlickrImportParameters READONLY

AS

    SET NOCOUNT on

    --  Extract list of cameras from the passed-in data
    --  Use the EXCEPT clause to filter out any items already in the target table
    --  Bonus: using EXCEPT removed dupicates
    INSERT TestTableCamera (AliasTitle, Make, Model)
     select CameraAliasTitle, CameraMake, CameraModel
      from @dataImported
     except select AliasTitle, Make, Model
      from TestTableCamera

    --  With camera now defined, join in on it by the "natural key"
    --  (AliastTitle, Make, Model uniquely identify a camera, it was
    --  either already in the table or we just added it, so we can
    --  just join on it)
    INSERT TestTableImage (AliasTitle, Title, Description, Hits, CameraId)
     select ttc.AdjustedAlias, di.Title, di.Description, di.Hits, ttc.Id
      from @dataImported di
       inner join TestTableCamera ttc
        on ttc.AliasTitle = di.CameraAliasTitle
         and ttc.Make = di.CameraMake
         and ttc.Model = di.CameraModel

RETURN 0
GO
```

Run the tests, and you’ll see it works (though because of the foreign key you’ll have to replace that `TRUNCATE TABLE` with

```
DELETE TestTableImage
DELETE TestTableCamera
```

Without the calculated column, you’d have to join on the unmodified AliasTitle; truncating that appended Id is ugly code and an ugly join, makes for a very strong argument on the calcluated column. (So why are you appending the ID to the alias?)

Of course, as written on a large table this could be very slow, as there’s no index to support that three-column join. The fix here is to either create such an index, or use the `output` clause to dump the three columns and the new identity value into a temp table, and perform join on that much smaller temp table.

Comment: how would i add to the image table as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081952/id-from-one-table-with-table-parameter-insert-into-other-table

Comment: I am adding alias title as the id will be removed for seo purposed to find the correct record